# Enthought TraitsUI based Python IDE

Tags: python, ide, enthought

Has anybody come across an Enthought TraitsUI (Envisage etc) based Python IDE?

I wonder why there is none, when Enthought Tool Suite makes it so easy to create extensible python GUI applications. 
One reason I can think  of, why such an IDE makes a lot of sense, is because it will be cross platform.

Any reason why such an IDE does not make sense?

Comment: Any Enthought guys here on StackOverFlow who would like to comment? I really want to know the pros and cons of this approach? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any reason why such an IDE does not
>   make sense?

Most people who use Python don't use the Enthought tool suite, so there's not enough interest to create a project (or demand for a company to sell a product).

I know that's not what you want to hear, so here's a few options:

1. Find a bunch of smart people who also like it and would like an IDE built with Enthought and build an IDE
2. Clamor for Enthought to make an IDE

You can always use Eclipse or another open-source IDE as a backend and just build a new UI.

Comment: Hi, I think i did not communicate correctly. My question is related to finding a general purpose Python IDE, which is itself built using Enthought suite. I personally think that making such a thing will make a lot of sense. And want to know from the community about it. :)

Comment: @Vishal I've edited my answer to make a bit more sense now that I know what you want. I've never used Enthought, but most Python users are interested in ease of development, native look and feel, and cross platform ability. If Enthought can do all of this, you may be able to get an IDE built with it.

Answer (score 0):

[Full disclosure: I work at Enthought]

I agree with you, the stack Traits + TraitsUI/pyface + Envisage makes a lot of sense to build a crossplatform IDE and is fairly simple. If you are interested in learning the stack and building one yourself, there are several open source examples that you could use to get started:
https://github.com/enthought/pyface/tree/master/examples
https://github.com/enthought/envisage/tree/master/example

We have also been working ourselves using that stack as the backbone. The next version of EPD, currently in beta, will ship with that IDE (free) in the coming couple months.